# How to open Documents folder using Storage Access Framework on Android 11 and higher?

Tags: android, android-11, storage-access-framework

This question only concerns Android 11 and above.

Reading about Android Storage Framework at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider, I am able to make my app create a file in the public `Downloads` directory of my app.

Doing the following opens the `Downloads` location for me and I am able to save a file.

```
private static final int WRITE_REQUEST_CODE = 101;

Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
i.setType("text/plain");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "someFile.txt");
startActivityForResult(i, WRITE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Above works great! But is the technique too different when I want my app to open the `Documents` folder instead of `Downloads`? How can I make my app open `Documents` folder on an Android 11 phone when the system dialog opens and be able to save the file there?

Please note that the intention is to create a document in Documents folder of the Android device.

Comment: The user gets to choose where to create the document. There is no requirement that they choose any particular provider (filesystem, Google Drive, etc.), let alone any particular document tree in the provider.

Comment: @CommonsWare Do you mean that the Downloads location opening is something that happens implicitly when I create an intent of `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`? Then is there no way that an Android app can create a file in public `Documents` folder of the device?

Comment: "Do you mean that the Downloads location opening is something that happens implicitly when I create an intent of ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT?" -- the choice of where that UI starts is up to the developers of that UI, which is a combination of Google and device manufacturers. You should not assume any particular starting point.

Comment: "Then is there no way that an Android app can create a file in public Documents folder of the device?" -- the *user* chooses where the *user* wants the *user's* content to go on the *user's* device (or in the user's cloud storage). If the user wants it in `Documents/`, the user can choose that location. Or, they can choose another location. Now, if your complaint is that the SAF UI is awful, I definitely will not argue.

Comment: Ah. This SAF UI is a bit confusing. Yes. I now figured out that I can traverse to the Documents location and save my file there. Yes, this is awful UI :D

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks a lot. Your explanations answer my question!

Comment: "This SAF UI is a bit confusing" -- that's like saying I'm a bit balding. 

Comment: @CommonsWare :D :D :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Doing the following opens the Downloads location for me

Not necessarily. There is no guaranteed "point of entry", and you should not assume any particular location.

> How can I make my app open Documents folder on an Android 11 phone when the system dialog opens

Unless you had previously gotten a `Uri` for `Documents/` from `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`/`ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree`, you do not have a way to do that.

Note, though, that users can go to `Documents/` or any other tree of their choosing through the UI that is opened by your code. Unfortunately, that UI is not very intuitive for newcomers.